# In how many ways can 12 similar balls be divided into three identical groups, with each group containing at least one and at most six balls?

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

**My attempt :-**

a+b+c=12 ; I am assuming the groups be distinct for the time being

We need to distribute 1 ball to each group, which would make our equation as follows

x+y+z=9

Now, ways of distributing 9 identical objects into 3 distinct groups could be done in ${11 \choose 2} = 55$ ways

From these 55 ways we would have some cases in which a group gets more than 6 objects and thus violating the condition present in the question

Hence correction for that :- Let me choose one group in ${3 \choose 1}$ ways and give 6 more objects to that particular group, such that now that group in total has 7 objects in it , the remaining 9-6 = 3 identical objects can be distributed into three groups in ${5 \choose 2}$ ways,

Hence the correction will be as :-

$55-({3 \choose 1}*{5 \choose 2}) = 25$ ways

These 25 ways will be such that all groups will be having atleast 1 ball and at most 6 balls in them

From here I know that I need to subtract some more cases as I took my assumption of all groups to be distinct , but I am not sure how to proceed from here, please help me

---

By manual counting, I know there are 6 cases as follows :-

6,5,1

6,4,2

6,3,3

5,5,2

4,4,4

How should I subtract those 19 cases from the 25 cases I got so far ?

Comment: The wording of the question does not make sense.  Groups of different sizes cannot be identical.  My guess is that you wish to divide $12$ indistinguishable balls into three groups, each with at least one ball and at most six balls.

Comment: And are you drawing a distinction between "similar" and "identical"?  I think that all you mean is that balls are indistinguishable and that rearranging the groups doesn't matter.  Thus the arrangement $\{1, 2, 9\}$ is the same as the arrangement $\{9, 1,2\}$.  Is this correct?  If so, direct counting is easy enough, as you have remarked.  In this case, I'd say direct counting is a lot easier than counting the complement.  The complement has a lot more cases, as you have noticed.

Answer (score 2):

**Different Approach**

It is a partition question. If each partition,i.e group, should contain at least one ball,then give them one ball.

Now, we had groups each have one ball, then the question turn out to be distributing the rest $9$ identical balls into those three identical groups such that each group can have at most $5$ balls.This means that a group may not get any ball while we distribute the rest $9$ balls.

So, after we give one ball to each group, the question converted into partition of $9$ where a partition can have at most $5$ balls. Right ?

To solve our new partition problem , we will make use of [Gaussian Binomial Coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient)

Then according to formula $$r=9,m=3,n=5$$ $$B(5,3,9)=[q^9]\binom{8}{3}_9$$ $$[q^9]\frac{(1-q^8)(1-q^7)(1-q^6)}{(1-q)(1-q^2)(1-q^3)}=6$$

You can check the expansion using wolfram.